# TLC cannot handle this conjunct of the spec

Tags: tla+, tlc

I have a TLA+ module, which, summarized, looks like this:

```
--- MODULE Group ---

CONSTANTS People
VARIABLES members

Join(person) == ...
Leave(person) == ...

Init == members \subseteq People

Next == \E p \in People :
            \/ Join(p)
            \/ Leave(p)

====================
```

When I try to model-check this with TLC, I get the following error:

> TLC threw an unexpected exception.
>   This was probably caused by an error in the spec or model.
>   See the User Output or TLC Console for clues to what happened.
>   The exception was a java.lang.RuntimeException
>   : 
>   TLC cannot handle this conjunct of the spec:
>   line X, col Y to line Z, col T of module Group

...pointing to the entire content of `Next`.

I believe my `Next` is well-written, because here's an example model that has a very similar `Next` to mine: https://github.com/tlaplus/Examples/blob/master/specifications/aba-asyn-byz/aba_asyn_byz.tla#L110

Also, section 14.2.2 of [Leslie Lamport's *Specifying Systems*](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/book.html) says:

> TLC can evaluate a set-valued expression only if that expression equals a finite set[...].  TLC will evaluate expressions of the following forms only if it can enumerate the set *S*:

and provides the example of "there exists *x* in *S* such that *p*".

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You need to provide a minimal self-contained example. Try to reduce your code to a small example that shows the error. Also are you sure it points to `Next`? Because that's a disjunct, not a conjunct. It's more likely to be a problem in `Spec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my use of `\subseteq` in `Init`, as answered here: [\in works, while \subseteq gives a "identifier undefined" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426052/in-works-while-subseteq-gives-a-identifier-undefined-error)