# \in works, while \subseteq gives a "identifier undefined" error

Tags: tla+, tlc

I have the following spec:

```
------------------------------ MODULE Group ------------------------------
CONSTANTS People
VARIABLES members

Init == members \subseteq People

Next == members' = members

Group == Init /\ [][Next]_members

=============================================================================
```

(I simplified this spec to the point where it's not doing anything useful.)

When I try to run it through TLC, I get the following error:

> In evaluation, the identifier members is either undefined or not an operator.

The error points to the `Init` line.

When I change the `Init` line to:

```
Init == members \in People
```

it validates fine.

I want the former functionality because I mean for `members` to be a collection of People, not a single person.

According to section 16.1.6 of [Leslie Lamport's *Specifying Systems*](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/book.html), "TLA+ provides the following operators on sets:" and lists both `\in` and `\subseteq`.

Why is TLA+ not letting me use `\subseteq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that is a valid TLA+ expression, TLC can only assign next-state values to a variable `x` by the statements `x' = e` or `x' \in S`. See section 14.2.6 for details. This holds for the initial assignment, too. In your case, you probably want `members \in SUBSET People`.